# Kafka: Throughput of producing to thousands of topics with different message rate

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

The task is routing messages from a single huge source topic to many (few thousands) destination topics. Overall rate is about few millions of records per second. It barely handles such payload now, and we are looking for a solution to optimise it. However, it does not seem it reached any limit at hardware or network level, so I suppose it can be improved. A latency isn't important (few minutes delay is fine), an average message size is less than 1 KiB.

The most obvious way to increase throughput is to make `batch.size` and `linger.ms` larger. But the problem is a different message rate in destination topics: depends on a message destination the rate may vary from few messages per second to hundreds of thousands per second.

As I understand (please, correct me if I'm wrong), but `batch.size` is per-partition parameter. So, if we set `batch.size` too big we will go out of memory, because it was multiplied by a number of destination topics even all of them have only one partition. Otherwise, if `batch.size` will be small, then producer will send requests to broker too often. In each app instance we use a single producer for all destination topics (`ProduceRequest` can include batches to different topics). The only way to set this parameter different per topic is using a separate producer per topic, but it means thousands of threads and many context switches.

Can we set a *minimum* size of actual `ProduceRequest`, i.e. like `batch.size`, but for overall batches in the request, i.e. something opposite to `max.request.size`?

Or is there any way to increase throughput of producer?

Comment: How did you find that the problem is in the producers and not on the brokers? How many partitions do you have for the incoming topic? Are you sure there are no hot partitions? Do brokers replicate? Are the replicas lagging, which will slow down the producers? How many producers do you have and at what rate do they produce? There are many reasons why you might have this issue, but you need to share a lot more data about your setup to answer *is there any way to increase throughput of producer?*

Comment: > How many partitions do you have for the incoming topic
630 partitons in source topic

Comment: "Are you sure there are no hot partitions"
Source topic partitions are well balanced (random partitioning, no skews)

Comment: "Do brokers replicate?"

RF=3 for all topics

Comment: "How many producers do you have and at what rate do they produce?"

For source topic is about 2k producers. For destination we tried 5-10 stream app instances.

Comment: "you need to share a lot more data about your setup to answer"

I understand. It's quite complex, and it's hard to provide a full spec in one question, sorry. I just hope, maybe there are some technics or tricks or something else. The only why I'm pretty sure that it can handle more, it's because hardware resources (CPU, RAM, IO, network) _are not_ completely exhausted. So, I suppose it's limited by something else, e.g. OS settings (like disk scheduler or ulimit, which we already tried to tune).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem looks solveable and seems like we solved. it's not a big problem for Kafka to stream to 3k topics, but there are some things you should take care about:

1. Kafka-producer tries to allocate `batch.size * number_of_destination_partitions` memory on the start. if you have `batch.size` equals `10mb` and `3k` topics with `1` partition per topic, Kafka-producer will require at least `~30gb` on the start ([source code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2b2039f0ba88e210dd09031291c050cfcda7ce4a/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/RecordAccumulator.java#L336)).
   so the more destination partitions you have, the less `batch.size` you have to set up or the more memory you need. we chose small `batch.size`
2. messages rate per destination topics does't affect general performance. Kafka-producer sends several batches per one request. here `max.request.size` comes into the play ([source code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2b2039f0ba88e210dd09031291c050cfcda7ce4a/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/RecordAccumulator.java#L862), `maxSize` is `max.request.size`). the higher `max.request.size`, the more batches could be sent per one request. it is important to understand that reaching a `batch.size` or a `linger.ms` don't instantly triggers sending batch to the broker. as soon as batch reaches the `batch.size` or the `linger.ms`, it is marked as sendable and will be processed later with other batches ([source code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2b2039f0ba88e210dd09031291c050cfcda7ce4a/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/RecordAccumulator.java#L619)).
   moreover, `batch.size` or a `linger.ms` are not the only reasons to mark batch as sendable (check the previous link). and this is where the batches are actually sent ([source code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2b2039f0ba88e210dd09031291c050cfcda7ce4a/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/Sender.java#L849)). that's why the same events rate per destination topics is not required, but still there are some nuances which will be described next.

   2.1. a few words about `linger.ms`. can't say for sure how it acts in this scenario. on the one hand, the larger it is, the longer Kafka-producer will wait to collect messages for exact partition and the more data for that partition will be send per one request. one the other hand, it seems like the less it is, there more batches for different partitions could be packed into one request. while there is no certainty about how to do better.
3. despite that Kafka-producer is able to send more than one batch per request, it can't send more that one batch per request for one specific partition. thats why if you have skewed messages rate for destination topics, you have to increase partitions count for most loaded ones to increase throughput. but it's always necessary to remember that an increasing partitions count leads to an increase in memory usage.

actually, an information above helped us to solve our problems with performance. but there may be other nuances that we don't know about yet.

I hope it will be useful.